# Killed bash process keep restarting

Tags: process, kill, ps

The server has a running `bash` process with 2200% CPU usage:

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep 10986
root     10986 2198  1.8 2483184 2437820 ?     Ssl  13:23 962:25 -bash
```

The process has 22 `-bash` threads as shown in `htop`.

[image: htop screenshot]

When using `strace`, the parent process keeps `epoll_pwait()` and the child threads keeps `sched_yield()`.

I tried `kill -9 10986` but after few minutes the bash process restarts with same high CPU usage.

Someone told me that hours earlier he used `screen` to run a bash script that looks like this:

```bsh
./prog <arg1>
./prog <arg2>
./prog <arg3>
...
```

But when he logged in again the whole directory disappeared and the process keep unkillable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate all user's bash sessions instead of killing self regenerating processes one by one: `pkill -9 bash` from user, which launched all those sessions.

To track what launces new bash processes, run terminal. Then run `journalctl -f | grep bash` inside of it and see what changes after some bash process was killed. You could not kill all bash processes now, because of this will kill the session with journalctl.

You could also try `ps f -g PID` to see some bash process tree. Those bash processes are children of some parent process you need to get name of.

If killed processes are being regenerated again, then they are scheduled in crontab or launched by systemd service.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and the session end, CPU works fine again.  However, few seconds later the bash process comes back. How can I tell if there's another process trying to relaunch the bash? Maybe the `screen` program?

Comment: You need to find out a parent of these bash processes. It could be some systemd service that starts it.

Comment: `journalctl` doesn't report anything about `bash` even after it restarts. The parent of the  bash process is `init` process (pid=1). There's only 1 bash process and all the other 22 bashes are threads of the bash process.

Comment: Then try without `grep bash`. Check also `sudo crontab -e`, `cat /etc/profile | grep bash`, `cat /etc/profile.d/* | grep bush` and the same for bahrc. Also check `cat /etc/systemd/system/* | grep bash` and all files in subdirectories system/*/*. `/lib/systemd/system` also could be verified.

Comment: Thanks for all your hints! The `crontab` is modified and it looks like a malicious program.

Comment: @zingdle I'm a regular at [security.se] and my advice for you is to completely re-install the entire OS. At this point, you can't trust that machine anymore.

Comment: @MechMK1 Thanks for your advice! I'll reinstall the OS as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have encoutered the same virus

You can check the `/etc/cron*/sync`. use `chattr -i` to make it deletable. then delete it. The virus exe is `/bin/sysdrr`

I found it by `jounalctl | grep cron` and this line `May 13 09:17:01 micagent-S2600CW CRON[31589]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)` matches the start time of the virus process. So I looked into it and find the `-bash` being executed and deleted.

`sudo crontab -e` didn't show this place. I am not familiar with it. For those noobs like me, go to /etc/cron*/sync.